# Re-enabling access to keyboard in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I am trying to disable the mouse completely in my textarea (#texttype) but make it so that when you click the wrapper (#line) it moves the cursor to the end of what has been written in the textarea. The code below almost works but once the textarea is deselected, clicking the wrapper doesn't put the cursor back to the end, it's like the text area is locked so the user can't type anymore...

HTML:

```
<div id ="line">
  <textarea wrap="off" draggable="false" id="texttype" name="texttype" spellcheck="false" class="type" onkeyup="countChar(this)" onkeypress="keypressed(e)"></textarea>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var toggle_mouse = $('#line').mousedown(function(event){
    $('#texttype').focus(function(){
        this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = this.value.length;
    });
});

var mouse_off = $('#texttype').mousedown(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var mouse_off = $('#texttype').mousedown(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
})
.focus(function () {
    this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = this.value.length;
});

var toggle_mouse = $('#line').mousedown(function (event) {
    mouse_off.focus();
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/P3Bkp/

Your mistake was that you tried to bind textarea focus event inside mousedown event handler. You should not do that.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you so much. Thanks for the advice on the textarea focus as well, I won't be doing that again.

Comment: You should not bind any events inside other event handlers. Any time event is fired you rebind one more handler. After 5 focus you would have 5 event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

not sure this would work - but possibly making the text un-selectable instead of disabling the mouse?

```
#textarea a {
 -webkit-user-select:none; 
 -moz-user-select:none; 
 -ms-user-select:none; 
 user-select:none;
}
```